# Is the pushout of smooth varieties along a smooth closed subvariety again a variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cobordism, schemes

The following question is motivated by a desire to find a rough analog in algebraic geometry of the usual notion of gluing of smooth bordisms.

Suppose k is an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0,
A, B, and C are smooth varieties over k,
and f: A→B and g: A→C are closed regular embeddings of varieties.
Although the category of schemes (or varieties over k) is not cocomplete,
Corollary 3.9 in Karl Schwede's paper [Gluing schemes and a scheme without closed points](http://personal.psu.edu/kes32/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf)
says that the pushout of f and g in the category of schemes exists.
Is this pushout a (not necessarily irreducible) variety over k,
i.e., a reduced separated scheme of finite type over k?

Comment: If you glue together varieties $B$ and $C$ along $A$, you don't necessarily get something irreducible right?

Comment: @J. C. Ottem: No, as the example of A=Spec k, B=C=k[t] demonstrates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying your question.

Comment: I believe this is true but it's been a long time since I thought it.  I think separatedness is ok once you know Noetherian, by the valuative criterion.  Reducedness is local and then obvious  (remember the pullback of the rings is a subring of the product of the two rings you are gluing).  So the only question is whether it is finite type.  I don't know where to find the finite type condition written down though (it's also local).  But see 5.3.2 in Ferrand's paper *Conduteur, Descente et Pincement*.  In particular, the $B \coprod C$ is finite over the gluing, so this should get you close.

Comment: This interesting question boilds down to: If $A,B,C$ are finitely generated $k$-algebras and $B \twoheadrightarrow A$, $C \twoheadrightarrow A$ are surjective homomorphisms, is then the fiber product $B \times_C A$ also finitely generated?

Comment: @Martin: Sure, but your statement is quite a bit stronger (e.g., no conditions on smoothness and regularity).  In your formula for the fiber product you should exchange A and C.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Since you are assuming all your schemes $A,B,C$ are smooth, so in particular they are regular, so regular embedding is same as usual embedding  : see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0E9J. I guess, in the formulation of Martin Brandenburg's comment, the only thing he is missing is that $A,B,C$ are regular and integral domains.